# Highlight candlesticks in Apexchart

Tags: angular, apexcharts, candlestick-chart, candlesticks, ng-apexcharts

I have a candlestick chart inside an Angular Component that asynchrounously should highlight the border of a specific candlestick... I'm using apexchart 3.40.0 and ng-apexchart 1.7.4...In my mind, I'd like to achieve something with darker border as:

```
                    strokeDashArray: 4, // Imposta un modello di tratteggio per la linea (opzionale)
                    borderColor: '#FF5733', // Colore del bordo per la linea
                    borderWidth: 2, // Spessore della linea
```

Could you help me, please?

I'm trying to use the updateOptions method with body for the moment that adds a marker:

```
{
   annotations: {
      points: [{
        x: input.x, // X-axis value where you want to highlight (timestamp)
        y: input.y[2],
        marker: {
          size: 6,
          fillColor: "#fff",
          strokeColor: "#2698FF",
          radius: 2
        }
      ]}
}
```

but when I pass the full array to y, it does nothing.